# SharePoint ListItemCollection.GetById returns empty ListItem?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, listitem

So im trying to retrieve data from a sharepoint server ListItem

The only problem is that this part here:

> collection.GetById(itemId)

returns a completly empty ListItem instead of the ListItem corresponding to the id

when i check with the debugger the item is indeed inside the collection and all the data is in there.

How do i correct this or am i missing something essential here?

```cs
        public Dictionary<string, object> GetPendingEmployeeItem(int itemId)
        {
            var list = _app.Sharepoint.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("New Employee");
            var query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "<View></View>";

            var collection = list.GetItems(query);
            _app.Sharepoint.Load(collection, items => items.Include(
                item => item.Id,
                item => item.DisplayName,
                item => item.FieldValuesAsText));
            _app.Sharepoint.ExecuteQuery();

            return ConvertToDictionary(collection.GetById(itemId));
        }

        private Dictionary<string, object> ConvertToDictionary(ListItem item)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var pair in item.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues)
            {
                dic.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            return dic;
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you add an empty <Where></Where> clause to your ViewXml (Query), also maybe you have to add the Viewfields to the query, I'm not sure.

Comment: As far as i can see i changed the ViewXML to this
`<View><Where></Where></View>`
And it doesnt seem to have changed anything also how do you mean add the Viewfield,s like this?
`<FieldRef Name='ID'/>`

Comment: Why you are first requesting a list of item and then get just one of them? Why don't you just use the getItemById method from the SPList object? Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee546240(v%3Doffice.15)

Comment: Same problem when i use the suggested method the ListItem has no data stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution. i dont know why it wouldn't work before, but i guess as long as it works now it is fine.

Instead of using the given Methods *GetById / GetItemById* i simply worked around them with *First*.
Either i missed something or these methods are broken.

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetPendingEmployeeItem(int itemId)
    {
        var list = _app.Sharepoint.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("New Employee");
        var query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View></View>";

        var collection = list.GetItems(query);

        _app.Sharepoint.Load(collection);
        _app.Sharepoint.ExecuteQuery();

        return collection.First(item => item.Id.Equals(itemId)).FieldValues;
    }
```